# Problem with array of objects in mongoose schema

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have problem with rest api based on node express and mongodb with mongoose i think i have problem with mongoose schema of nested array of objects

i tried console log req.body and there are data but when i use new schema of mongoose then there are empty array

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const TranslationSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required:true
        },
    description: {
        type: String
    },
    laguage_code: {
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
})

const ImagesSchema = new Schema({
    name:{
        type: String
    },
    file_id: {
        type: String
    }
})
const RecipeSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users'
    },
    translations:[TranslationSchema],
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    images:[ImagesSchema]
})
module.exports = Recipe = mongoose.model("recipes", RecipeSchema);
```

and api

```
router.post(
    '/',
    passport.authenticate('jwt', { session:false }),
    (req,res) => {
        const newRecipe = new Recipe({
            user: req.user.id,
            translations:req.body.translations,
            images:req.body.images
        })
        console.log(req.body)
        console.log(newRecipe)
        // newRecipe.save().then(recipe => res.json(recipe))
    }
)
```

on console.log req.body i have

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  images: '[{name:\'test\', file_id:\'asd\'}]',
  translations: '[{name:\'asd\', laguage_code:\'pl\'}]' }
```

but on console.log(newRecipe)

```
{ _id: 5ca0cc632314cd4368bf42dd,
  user: 5c569f603e811118c83c80d1,
  translations: [],
  date: 2019-03-31T14:19:15.788Z,
  images: [] }
```

what i make wrong?

Comment: `images: '[{name:\'test\', file_id:\'asd\'}]',` That's a "string" and not an array. This is really a problem with whatever is sending the POST request sending malformed data. Note that you cannot even `JSON.parse()` this since the keys are not quoted properly. Best to check the source that is submitting the data. It should look like `images: [{ name: 'test', file_id: 'asd' }]'` in the result of a `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body, undefined, 2))` when it's submitted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Recipe` model you have defined `translations` and `images` as mongoose models too. So try to export these models and construct them. For example:

```
const translations = new Translation(req.body.translations);
const images = new Image(req.body.images);
```

And then try create the model this way:

```
const newRecipe = new Recipe({
    user: req.user.id,
    translations:translations,
    images:images
})
```

I hope i gave you an idea how to try find your solution.